# Keyboard issue in iOS11

Tags: swift, xcode, ios11

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let rect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

    }
}
```

By the way, function does not give correct RectValue.
Whats wrong with this?

Comment: What's wrong in the rect you're getting?

Comment: This does not contain height for QuickTypeBar.

Comment: Which type bar? Are you talking about the AutoCorrect bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

 func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let rect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        }
    }
 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let rect = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

        }
    }
```

Comment: `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey ` should be in `keyboardWillHide` and `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` should be in `keyboardWillShow`